# Typescript TS5042 Build: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I am receiving the following error across all typescript projects that I am trying run.

```
TS5042  Build: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line.
```

I have downloaded a free Typescript Angular2 template, ran it and this error immediately pops up.

Has it got something to do with my global typescript installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a fix that works for me. I have more than one version of Visualstudio at c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

Open v15.0 and copy the Typescript folder to the v14.0 folder.

Answer (score 24):

The `tsc` command can be run in two ways:

1. With a `project` parameter, which points to the directory that contains a `tsconfig.json`.  For example:  `tsc --project ./app`. The location of the `tsconfig.json` determines the set of files that should be included in the compilation. See here for more about the `tsconfig.json`: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html
2. With a list of files as the default parameter.  For example: `tsc MyFile1.ts MyFile2.ts MyFile3.ts`.

These two options are incompatible with each other because they both attempt to define which files should be compiled.

What is the command you are using to compile your project?  Or are you using an IDE that runs the build for you?

[Here's the reference for the `tsc` compiler options.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: I see the OP has marked `visual-studio-2015` as an IDE. I'm having the exact same issue ever since I installed TS 1.8. I've uninstalled and reinstalled every version of TS 1.7 available and nothing is fixing this issue.

Answer (score 10):

i was getting same error but when removed every space in my folders name as shown in path from tsc compiler it now successfully builds.See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32400).

Comment: Yup. This was the issue for me in VS Code

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was pretty simple. I looked at the filepath for my project and realized one of the folder names in the file path had a space in it. When I renamed the folder without the space, TSC -p worked just fine. It seems like TSC, when parsing out command line args, splits it at spaces so it saw the part of my filepath name after the space as a file to compile.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this error was connected with husky / lint-staged configuration when running pre-commit hook. I had `.lintstagedrc.json` with the following

```json
{
  "*.ts": "npm run lint",
    "*.{ts,js,html,scss,md,json}": "prettier --write"
}
```

My linter script uses `tsc -p myConf.json --noEmit`. But `lint-staged` appends filenames under the hood, so it works like `tsc -p myConf.json --noEmit myFileA.ts myFyleB.ts`, which is wrong and causes the issue.

My approach was to convert json config into `lint-staged.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  '*.ts': () => 'npm run lint',
  '*.{ts,js,html,scss,md,json}': 'prettier --write'
};
```

Comment: This worked for me, but why?

Comment: @penguinflip It's because of lint-staged magic, as I mentioned in the answer: lint-staged appends filenames under the hood, which makes the end command incorrect. Perhaps function notation in js config eliminates this magic.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error with NX and what fixed the error for me was removing the spaces in the project's path.

Example:

```
"C:\The Project Path\project-dir" renamed to "C:\TheProjectPath\project-dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

If could be of help I have a little update. As explained in the previous issues, after I've seen the problems with 1.8 I tried to uninstall it and reinstall 1.7 to continue to work to my projects, but even the installation was ok I had different problems compiling these asp.net 5 apps. I tried repairing vs, uninstalling and reinstalling 1.7 and 1.8 in any order without any changes. 
In the end I checked the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript and I found that at the end of the uninstall of every version of typescript I have this

[search for this folder and delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JInwx.png)
At this point I tried to remove this directory completely and retried to uninstall typescript 1.7.6. and now it works fine.
I tried doing this cleaning up and installing 1.8 beta, but I continue to have the same problem, but at least now I can work on asp.net 5 projects.
I think that the problem rolling back to previous version was unable to overwrite at least the TypeScript.Tasks.dll generating an inconsistent behavior.
Could be possibile that to make work nightly builds of 1.8

and the error TS5042 solve. I hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, it is best to only put answers in the Answers. If you have a new question, post that as a new question and not an answer to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Not use Powershell. Use the old command.com in your configuration.

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"` to the visual studio code user settings.