# target in tsconfig.json setting not working but command works?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

I have `tsconfig.json` as above, and when I run command `tsc app.ts --watch`, I hit error

> Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher

If I explicitly set the target in my command, it works

```
tsc -t es5 app.ts --watch
```

Any lead to which part may have gone wrong, why the discrepancy between two outcomes?

**UPDATES**

[image]

Comment: Are you running the `tsc` command in the same directory as `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: @Evert: Yes definitely

Comment: U sure? Usually I'd expect an `app.ts` to live in a `src/` dir and a `tsconfig.json` in the root of a project.

Comment: @Evert: I would agree with you but this is only a test project to understand the concept. Kindly refer to the attached screenshot

Comment: Ok! Sorry for assuming otherwise. If you use `-p tsconfig.json`, does it work?

Comment: @Evert I ran `tsc -p tsconfig.json app.ts --watch` and I ran into new issue "error TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line"

Comment: Ah, going out of a limb, but... is it possible that tsconfig.json is ignored you target specific files? Usually I just run `tsc` alone and rely on my `tsconfig.json` to determine which files to compile and where to save the results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813033/typescript-ts5042build-option-project-cannot-be-mixed-with-source-files-on-a

Comment: @Evert: Yup I tried `tsc --watch` and indeed error gone away but why...hmm..

Comment: Idk why that decision was made to be honest. But, I `tsc` on all my files so never really ran into this.

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) says

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

That's why when you run `tsc app.ts --watch`, your tsconfig.json file isn't being applied. You're providing `app.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

it might not work for everyone else but running `tsc index.ts --watch` worked for me.
You can try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [restarted your typescript server](https://tinytip.co/tips/vscode-restart-ts/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20restart%20the%20server,TypeScript%3A%20Restart%20TS%20server%22.), it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).